# Only define variable if item exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

With the help of several kind folks on this site, I was able to get a variation of the below script to populate some text field based on a selection they make in a drop down menu. Basically, they select their location from the drop down and it populate text fields with their address (`input_19`) and city, state and ZIP code (`input_21`). When expanding this to multiple uses, I realized that sometimes the suite number needs to be in a separate field so I added two additional variables that split the address (`input_26`) and suite number (`input_21`). In cases where there is no `input_21`, it appears the the scrip fails. Is there a way to use the portion of the script only if the field exists?

```
// JavaScript Document

// Pre populated array of data
var myData1 = new Array();
myData1['Addison'] = '14295 Midway Road, Suite 100';
myData1['Arlington'] = '1241 W. Green Oaks Blvd., Suite 101';
myData1['Colleyville'] = '1210 Hall Johnson Road, Suite 150';
myData1['Fire Wheel'] = '650 Beebalm Lane, Suite 260';
myData1['Flower Mound'] = '3020 Corporate Court, Suite 400';
myData1['Fort Worth'] = '4421 Oak Park Lane, Suite 102';
myData1['Legacy'] = '7500 Dallas Pkwy., Suite 175';
myData1['Mansfield'] = '1405 N. Highway 287, Suite 101';
myData1['McDermott'] = '3915 McDermott Road, Suite 2000';
myData1['Preston Center'] = '8201 Preston Road, Suite 450';
var myData2 = new Array();
myData2['Addison'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
myData2['Arlington'] = 'Arlington, TX 76013';
myData2['Colleyville'] = 'Colleyville, TX 76034';
myData2['Fire Wheel'] = 'Garland, TX 75040';
myData2['Flower Mound'] = 'Flower Mound, TX 75028';
myData2['Fort Worth'] = 'Fort Worth, TX 76109';
myData2['Legacy'] = 'Plano, TX 750241';
myData2['Mansfield'] = 'Mansfield, TX 76063';
myData2['McDermott'] = 'Plano, TX 75025';
myData2['Preston Center'] = 'Dallas, TX 75225';
var myData3 = new Array();
myData3['Addison'] = 'Suite 100';
myData3['Arlington'] = 'Suite 101';
myData3['Colleyville'] = 'Suite 150';
myData3['Fire Wheel'] = 'Suite 260';
myData3['Flower Mound'] = 'Suite 400';
myData3['Fort Worth'] = 'Suite 102';
myData3['Legacy'] = 'Suite 175';
myData3['Mansfield'] = 'Suite 101';
myData3['McDermott'] = 'Suite 2000';
myData3['Preston Center'] = 'Suite 450';
var myData4 = new Array();
myData4['Addison'] = '14295 Midway Road';
myData4['Arlington'] = '1241 W. Green Oaks Blvd.';
myData4['Colleyville'] = '1210 Hall Johnson Road';
myData4['Fire Wheel'] = '650 Beebalm Lane';
myData4['Flower Mound'] = '3020 Corporate Court';
myData4['Fort Worth'] = '4421 Oak Park Lane';
myData4['Legacy'] = '7500 Dallas Pkwy.';
myData4['Mansfield'] = '1405 N. Highway 287';
myData4['McDermott'] = '3915 McDermott Road';
myData4['Preston Center'] = '8201 Preston Road';




var element = document.querySelector('form.cart');
element.input_1.onchange = updateText;
function updateText() {
var obj_sel = element.input_1;
element.input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel.value];
var obj_sel = element.input_1;
element.input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel.value];
var obj_sel = element.input_1;
element.input_26.value = myData3[obj_sel.value];
var obj_sel = element.input_1;
element.input_31.value = myData4[obj_sel.value];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object doesn't exist your script will throw an error, since you are trying to assign a property to `undefined`. Since you don't [catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) that error, the script will just stop running at that point. You can use an if statement to confirm that the object is not `undefined`, before you try to set its value. You also don't need to repeat `var obj_sel = element.input_1;` each time you use it:

```
function updateText() {
  var obj_sel_value = element.input_1.value;

  if(element.input_19)
    element.input_19.value = myData1[obj_sel_value];
  if(element.input_21)
    element.input_21.value = myData2[obj_sel_value];
  if(element.input_26)
    element.input_26.value = myData3[obj_sel_value];
  if(element.input_31)
    element.input_31.value = myData4[obj_sel_value];
}
```

That should fix your problem, but there are other things you can do to make your code better and save yourself time in the future. For example, rather than have a variable for each `myData` object, you  could use an array of objects. If you find yourself suffixing your variable names with a number, that is a good indication that you should consider replacing all those variables with one array.

```
var myData = [];
myData[0] = {};
myData[0]['Addison'] = '14295 Midway Road, Suite 100';
...
myData[0]['Preston Center'] = '8201 Preston Road, Suite 450';
myData[1]['Addison'] = 'Addison, TX 75001';
...
myData[1]['Preston Center'] = 'Dallas, TX 75225';
myData[2] = {};
...
...
```

Also notice that I replaced your `new Array()` call with `{}`. This makes sense since you're using it like an object not an array. Javascript arrays are an ordered collection which is indexed by numeric keys. If you have string keys, you're working with an object, not an array. An object is an unordered collection of (key,value) pairs.